# JUnit4: Testing a read file method with type ArrayList

Tags: java, testing, junit4, file-management

I have written a test to check if my java method to read a .txt file will successfully execute

```
@Test
    public void testRead() {
        String filePath = "testpackread.txt";

        ArrayList<Card> testReaderMethod = FileManager.readFile(filePath);
        assertEquals(4,testReaderMethod);
    }
```

The file I open contains the number 4, all I want to do is have the **test pass if it reads the first line as 4**

The test runs and the method is successful, so the problem isn't how I wrote the method.
The output in the commandline shows:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: expected:<4> but was:<[project.Card@3043fe0e]>
```

If it helps this is method that is being tested:

```
    public static ArrayList<Card> readFile(String packPath){  
        ArrayList<Card> cardDeck = new ArrayList<>();
        int cardNumber;
       
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader (packPath));
            String line = in.readLine();
            while(line!= null){
                cardNumber = Integer.parseInt(line);
                if (cardNumber > 0) {
                    cardDeck.add(new Card(cardNumber));
                    line = in.readLine();
                }else {//If found invalid card stop immediately and clear cardDeck
                    System.out.println("[Message] : Integer must be positive");
                    cardDeck.clear();
                    line = null;
                }
           
            in.close();//Close file reader
        return cardDeck;
    }
```

**any help is greatly appreciated, I hope i've been clear**

Comment: Within `assertEquals()`, you are comparing two different types: an integer with an array list of type `Card`.

Comment: how to I solve that though?

Answer (score 1):

Your assertion is doing the equivalent of:

```
if (Integer.valueOf(4).equals(Arrays.asList(new Card(4))))
```

If you try that out, it also doesn't work, right?

Perhaps (if `Card` implements `equals`):

```
assertEquals(Arrays.asList(new Card(4)), testReaderMethod);
```

or

```
assertEquals(1, testReaderMethod.size());
assertEquals(4, testReaderMethod.get(0).getCardNumber());
```

Comment: what is getCardNumber() supposed to be?

Comment: You didn't give much information, but your sample showed `new Card(cardNumber)`, so I assumed that it was storing `cardNumber` in a field, so `getCardNumber` was the corresponding getter that I assumed existed by some name.